# How to bind ajax json data to custom struct type?

Tags: json, ajax, go, struct, bind

Why do not binding ajax json data for my custom struct type?

My env:

- golang
- echo framework

go binding function

```
/**
 *  function : Model Init
 */
func modelInit(c echo.Context) tetrisModel.Tetris {
    tetris := tetrisModel.DefaultInit()
    if err := c.Bind(tetris); err != nil {
        c.Logger().Error(err)
    }

    return *tetris
}
```

call modelInit

```
func Control(c echo.Context) tetrisModel.Tetris {
    tetris := modelInit(c)
    fmt.Println("=======================")
    fmt.Println(c.FormValue("nowBlockPositionX"))
    fmt.Println(tetris.NowBlockPositionX) // do not printing, why?
    fmt.Println("=======================")

    // ... ... other code... ... 
}
```

the result:

`fmt.Println(c.FormValue("nowBlockPositionX"))` > working

`fmt.Println(tetris.NowBlockPositionX)` not working / not printing, why? (do not binding)

**I hope, this code will print the '3'**

DefaultInit()

```
func DefaultInit() *Tetris {
    tetris := new(Tetris)

    // some default data setting...

    return tetris
}
```

tetris model code

```
type Tetris struct {
    NowBlockPositionX  int                `form:"nowBlockPositionX" json:"nowBlockPositionX"`
    NowBlockPositionY  int                `form:"nowBlockPositionY" json:"nowBlockPositionY"`
    NowBlock           map[string]int     `form:"nowBlock" json:"nowBlock"`

    // other data exists...
}
```

ajax json data(POST type)

```
{
    nowBlockPositionX: 3
    , nowBlockPositionY: 0
    , nowBlock: {L: 0}
    // other data exists...
}
```

I understand if go struct type has literal string (like this : `form:"nowBlock" json:"nowBlock"`) then the structure auto bind('Bind function'). isn't it?

Comment: Which import are you using for the `form:`? I am familiar with `https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/schema` which should work. Also json & schema look redundant: Just json should be sufficient when mapping.

Comment: I want only json literal. And other literal(`form:...`) is spare.